# An elegant/faster way to find the end points of a line on a image?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, for-loop, numpy-ndarray

I've been working to improve the speed of my code by replacing for loops of array operations to appropriate NumPy functions.

The function aims to get the end points of a line, which is the only two points that has exactly one neighbor pixel in 255.

Is there a way I could get two points from np.where with conditions or some NumPy functions I'm not familiar with will do the job?

def get_end_points(image):

```
x1=-1
y1=-1
x2=-1
y2=-1
    for i in range(image.shape[0]):
        for j in range(image.shape[1]):
            if image[i][j]==255 and neighbours_sum(i,j,image) == 255:
                if x1==-1:
                    x1 = j
                    y1 = i
                else:
                    x2=j
                    y2=i
return x1,y1,x2,y2
```

Comment: There are a few details that I'm not clear about. When you say neighbours, is it 4 or 8 surrounding pixels? (that is, do you include diagonal neighbours?) And the condition to find an end point is, that the pixel should have value 255 (`image[i][j]==255`) and the neighbours should sum... 255 or zero? What does `neighbours_sum` do? Maybe you could give an example of what an endpoint would look like, with values?

Comment: @jdehesa  neighbors are 8 surrounding pixels, because the line itself might not be horizontal or vertical. neighbours_sum return the sum of all neghbours pixel values. In my case, the value of line pixels is 255 , while the background pixels are 0 . For example, for a line ( (1,1),(2,2),(2,3),(3,4)), the endpoints are (1,1) ,(3,4) which have only one neighbour exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution with convolution:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.signal

def find_endpoints(img):
    # Kernel to sum the neighbours
    kernel = [[1, 1, 1],
              [1, 0, 1],
              [1, 1, 1]]
    # 2D convolution (cast image to int32 to avoid overflow)
    img_conv = scipy.signal.convolve2d(img.astype(np.int32), kernel, mode='same')
    # Pick points where pixel is 255 and neighbours sum 255
    endpoints = np.stack(np.where((img == 255) & (img_conv == 255)), axis=1)
    return endpoints

# Test
img = np.zeros((1000, 1000), dtype=np.uint8)
# Draw a line from (200, 130) to (800, 370)
for i in range(200, 801):
    j = round(i * 0.4 + 50)
    img[i, j] = 255
print(find_endpoints(img))
# [[200 130]
#  [800 370]]
```

EDIT:

You may also consider using Numba for this. The code would be pretty much what you already have, so maybe not particularly "elegant", but much faster. For example, something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

@nb.njit
def find_endpoints_nb(img):
    endpoints = []
    # Iterate through every row and column
    for i in range(img.shape[0]):
        for j in range(img.shape[1]):
            # Check current pixel is white
            if img[i, j] != 255:
                continue
            # Sum neighbours
            s = 0
            for ii in range(max(i - 1, 0), min(i + 2, img.shape[0])):
                for jj in range(max(j - 1, 0), min(j + 2, img.shape[1])):
                    s += img[ii, jj]
            # Sum including self pixel for simplicity, check for two white pixels
            if s == 255 * 2:
                endpoints.append((i, j))
                if len(endpoints) >= 2:
                    break
        if len(endpoints) >= 2:
            break
    return np.array(endpoints)

print(find_endpoints_nb(img))
# [[200 130]
#  [800 370]]
```

This runs comparatively faster in my computer:

```
%timeit find_endpoints(img)
# 34.4 ms ± 64.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
%timeit find_endpoints_nb(img)
# 552 µs ± 4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Also, it should use less memory. The code above assumes there will be only two endpoints. You may be able to make it even faster if you add parallelization (although you would have to make some changes, because you would not be able to modify the list `endpoints` from parallel threads).

Comment: Short, simple, and effective. Love it!

Comment: @葉品廷 Glad it helped. I added another option using Numba too, which can be faster.

Comment: Numba version works much faster. I've tried to applied numba.jit on other functions but doesn't work well.  Does it only works on functions with pure basic operations and numpy operations?

Comment: @葉品廷 I'm not really an expert on Numba, but note `jit` and `njit` (or `jit(nopython=True)`) is quite different, since the first may optimize at "Python level" only while the second is always "native" (native optimization is more restricted but quite faster). If you use `njit` and get an error it's usually because you are using some unsupported feature for native. You can read more about the whole thing in Numba docs and other places, but yes it's not always trivial to boost the performance of a function with Numba.

Comment: @葉品廷 Also, if you use a function that works in a "vectorized" way (e.g. the first `find_endpoints` in my answer), using Numba will probably not help much, since the hard work is already being performed natively in Python. It works well when you have tight loops that do some mathematical operations (i.e. try to avoid `if` branches, dynamically growing structures, etc.). And with `parallel=True` and `prange` you can make things parallel pretty much automatically, as long as you are careful about race conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I didnt notice you have grayscale image, but as far as the idea is concerned, nothing changed

I cannot give you exact solution, but I can give you faster way to find what you want

**1) a)** Find indexes (pixels) where is white [255,255,255]

```
indice =np.where(np.all(image==255, axis=2))
```

**1) b)** do your loops around this points
this is faster because you are not doing useless loops

---

**2)** This solution should be very very fast, but it will be hard to program

**a)** find the indexes like in 1)

```
indice =np.where(np.all(image==255, axis=2))
```

**b)** move indice array +1 in X axis and add it to image

```
indices = =np.where(np.all(image==255, axis=2))
indices_up = # somehow add to all indexes in x dimension +1 (simply move it up)
add_up = image[indices]+image[indices_up]
# if in add_up matrix is array with(rgb channel) [510,510,510] # 255+255, then it has neightbour in x+1
# Note that you cant do it with image of dtype uint8, because 255 is max, adding up you will end up back at 255
```

You have to this for all neighbours though  -> x+1,x-1,y+1,y-1, x+1,y+1....
It will be extra fast tough

**EDIT2:** I was able to make a script that should do it, but you should test it first

```
import numpy as np
image =  np.array([[0, 0, 0,   0,    0, 0,   0,0,0],
                   [0, 0, 255, 0,    0, 0,   0,0,0],
                   [0, 0, 255, 0,  255, 0,   0,0,0],
                   [0, 0, 0,   255,0,   255, 0,0,0],
                   [0, 0, 0,   0,  0,   255, 0,0,0],
                   [0, 0, 0,   0,  0,   0,   0,0,0],
                   [0, 0, 0,   0,  0,   0,   0,0,0]])

image_f = image[1:-1,1:-1] # cut image

i = np.where(image_f==255) # find 255 in the cut image
x = i[0]+1 # calibrate x indexes for original image 
y = i[1]+1 # calibrate y indexes for original image
# this is done so you dont search in get_indexes() out of image 

def get_indexes(xx,yy,image):
    for i in np.where(image[xx,yy]==255):
        for a in i:
            yield xx[a],yy[a]


# Search for horizontal and vertical duplicates(neighbours)

for neighbours_index in get_indexes(x+1,y,image):
    print(neighbours_index )

for neighbours_index in get_indexes(x-1,y,image):
    print(neighbours_index )

for neighbours_index in get_indexes(x,y+1,image):
    print(neighbours_index )

for neighbours_index in get_indexes(x,y-1,image):
    print(neighbours_index )
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I can at least provide an elegant solution using convolutions.

We can look for the amount of neighbouring pixels by convolving the original image with a 3x3 ring. Then we can determine if the line end was there if the center pixel also had a white pixel in it.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from scipy.signal import convolve2d
>>> a = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]])
>>> a
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]])

>>> c = np.full((3, 3), 1)
>>> c[1, 1] = 0
>>> c
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 1]])

>>> np.logical_and(convolve2d(a, c, mode='same') == 1, a == 1).astype(int)
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Feel free to see what the individual components produce, but for the sake of brevity I didn't include them here. And as you might have noticed, it does correctly reject cases where the line ends with two neighbouring pixels.

This you can of course convert to the arbitrary amount of indices of line endings with `np.where`:

```
np.array(np.where(result))
```